# Why did Luke hang around as a Force Ghost for so long?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, luke-skywalker

Obi-Wan and Yoda didn't stay around for long after the Battle of Endor, appearing only to express that the New Jedi Order is safe in Luke's hand(s). Anakin only stayed around long enough to say goodbyes.

But Luke hung around for very long time in the Legends canon. Long after his death, he kept pestering Cade Skywalker to become a Jedi again.

If he intends to stay conscious in the afterlife, he focuses his entire afterlife existence on Cade alone, when there's so much going on for him to intervene in instead.

Seriously, why does Luke want to hang around for so long anyway? Is he too attached to the corporeal world?

Comment: Although the tags say you are talking about Legends, it wouldn't hurt to mention it in the question.

Comment: Perhaps them being related gave them a stronger connection or something?

Comment: It's implied this is Legends though - Cade Skywalker doesn't exist in canon, and there's no canon publication set after the movies yet.

Comment: Obi-Wan died in year 32 (0 being *The Phantom Menace*), and made appearance in the next 2 films, which were years 35 and 36. How long was Luke a ghost and appearing to Cade? [My source is this timeline, not checked for accuracy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media)

Answer (score 4):

We're never given a reason in-universe, although there are examples of other Jedi - mostly Sith - appearing as Force ghosts centuries after their deaths. We've also never been given an explanation of how Force ghosts actually work, so we're kind of left with speculation.

My personal theory is that Luke feels responsible for the New Jedi Order, and stuck around to make sure it didn't fall again. So, yes, in that case you could say that Luke's attachment kept him around.

Out-of-universe, of course, Luke was used as a literary device to connect the Legacy era characters with the original ones.

Comment: Luke is dead in the books? Is the newest movie non-canon or are the books now retconned or what's going on?

Comment: @Daft, I think this explanation might be of use to you: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

Comment: @Daft - the Legacy series is part of Legends continuity. Besides, it takes place 127 years after "Return of the Jedi", so yes - Luke is definitely dead by that time.